# Counterexamples or reasonings about the transcendence of series involving the Möbius function, and polynomials in the denominator

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, diophantine-approximation, transcendental-number-theory

This afternoon I tried to read and understand some sections of the paper *Some Applications of Diophantine Approximation* by R. Tijdeman procedding from Number Theory for the Millenium III, A K Peters (2002).

I wondered about the transcendence of infinite sums that involve the Möbius function, denoted in this post as $\mu(n)$ for integers $n\geq 1$ (see if you want the corresponding Wikipedia [*Möbius function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) or the MathWorld encyclopedia that also is very good). My background on linear forms in logarithms isn't good, and neither I have a good intuition about these theories. I know that certain series involving the Möbius function have a good and deep mathematical content.

> **Question.** My belief is that for each polynomial $Q(x)$ with integer coefficients, that is $Q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$, such that for all $x>1$ is positive $Q(x)>0$ with degree $\deg(Q)\geq 2$ one has that the sum of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{Q(n)}$$ is transcendent. Can you find a counterexample or provide some reasoning about the veracity of the statement? **Many thanks.**

If it is very difficult to find the counterexample, then please add what work can be done to know what about the veracity of my belief. I hope that my question is interesting, and that you can provide some answer.

Comment: Many thanks upvoter, sincerely was a bad day!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense because $\sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}{Q(n)}$ is understood only for $Q(n)  =n^k$. Even if that $f(x) = \sum_n \mu(n) e^{-n x}$ is the inverse Mellin transform of $\Gamma(s)/\zeta(s)$ means there is some little hope to say something about $g(a)=\int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-ax} dx= \sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}{n+a}$ (which does converge by the PNT), if $Q$ is separable then $\sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}{Q(n)}=\sum_j \frac{g(a_j) }{Q'(a_j)}$

Comment: Many thanks for your remarks @reuns , my hope is that some user can to answer my question. Notice that you think this problem cannot be solved does not mean that other mathematicians can't solve it: I am asking about find a counterexample or provide reasonings about the veracity of my statement.

Comment: No this is not how mathematics work. For most sequences the mathematics don't care if $\lim c(k)$ is rational algebraic or transcendent. Thus to hope say something about it you need to find alternate (simpler) expressions. For $c(k)=\sum_{n \le k} \mu(n)/Q(n)$ it is obvious there are not (because if there was one it would be useful in the theory of $\zeta(s)$)